# How to make a recursive function return all possible solutions?

Tags: python, recursion

For this recursive function when you input a list such as [2,8,3,2,7,2,2,3,2,1,3,0], it will find a path from the first index to the index containing the value 0, but can only move through the list by index[i]+i or index[i]-i and cannot go past the bounds of the list or go to an index that has already been visited. So if you are at index[0] which equals 2, you can only move forward in the list by 2. Or if you are at index[3], you can only move forward or backwards in the list by 2 so you can go to either index[1] or index[5].

For the list [2,8,3,2,7,2,2,3,2,1,3,0] I get a solution which is [0,2,5,7,4,11], but there are more solutions such as [0,2,5,3,1,9,10,7,4,11]  and I am not sure how to get my function to continue searching for all the other ones.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I'd recommend you read the Help section on how to ask a good question and make a good post.

Comment: To add to that, it's generally very important to include what you've tried so far. We're much more here to help with specific questions of the form "I tried X, but it did not do what I expect and instead resulted in an error!" accompanied by a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) .. though it can be the case that a little code is just there to help readers understand a theory or help identify an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)!

Comment: @dfundako I added a specific example and more info, I hope you can open my question again and give some advice on it.

Comment: @ti7 I added a specific example and more info, I hope you can open my question again and give some advice on it.

Answer (score 1):

Pass in an empty list to start that you keep passing on. Add solutions to it as found.

Comment: Something of this form is likely what they're looking for; it wouldn't be uncommon for such a thing to benefit from a set too (perhaps ending when all recursively-generated values are members of the set)

Comment: I added a specific example, hope this can help to solve my question.

Comment: Post your function